# Opencv cv2.absdiff(img1, img2).sum() without temporary img

Tags: python, opencv, vision

**Is it possible to calculate cv2.absdiff(img1, img2).sum() without temporary img ?**

I have a video stream and I need some kind of image stabilization on the begining of my processing.
The absdiff gives fast and error dependent result on check different placement vectors with two following images, but I have to create, write and read a temporary image which one is used only for calculate the img.sum(). So it would be fine to eliminate these memory allocation, writing and reading steps.

```
def calcMatch(img1, img2):
    diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
    return diff.sum()
```

**Solution in python**

```
import cv2
import time

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img1 = img[10:330, 10:870]
img2 = img[20:340, 20:880]

start = time.clock()
d = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
s = d.sum()
t = time.clock() - start
print 'with absdiff ', t
print s

start = time.clock()
s = cv2.norm(img1, img2, cv2.NORM_L1)
t = time.clock() - start
print 'with norm L1 ',  t
print s
```

It gives significant speed up as on my laptop with a very stable ratio:
with absdiff  **0.00207574457822**
4315120
with norm L1  **0.000226647018223**
4315120.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`norm`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm) function with `NORM_L1` norm. C++ code:

```
double res = cv::norm(img1, img2, cv::NORM_L1);
```

Comment: not bad, i tested and faster than absdiff method. i hope can find more faster than this